# Rest Assured request file containing multiple inputs

Tags: rest-assured

I am writing rest assured tests for few of the API's. When testing/automating, I need to write different test inputs for testing the API. I am reading the input from a JSON file as of now, I would like to know if there is a way to store multiple inputs in a single file and read specific ones in the test? As I have quite a bit number of scenario's to test for each API and creating those many files is getting hectic.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Did you tried propertied file, you can store any data in key value pair and read it from any class.

Comment: I guess if the values are simple, the property file would work perfectly. My JSON inputs are ranging from 10 lines to 50 lines. So looking for any other alternative.